# How http_builed_query such string?

Tags: php, url

I want to get such string:

```
'campaigns?fields=campaigns.id,campaigns.settings.title'
```

I try like this:

```
$param = [
        'campaigns',
        'fields' => [
            'campaigns.id',
            'campaigns.settings.title'
        ]
    ];
```

But get this:

```
0=campaigns&fields[0]=campaigns.id&fields[1]=campaigns.settings.title
enter code here
```

How it edit?

Comment: Query is a string after `?`, so adding `campaigns` is not needed.

Comment: It is impossible to do this with `http_build_query()`, as 1) 'campaigns' is a path, not a query string parameter; and 2) a comma would be URL-encoded by the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do it with [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$param = [
        'campaigns',
        'fields' => [
            'campaigns.id',
            'campaigns.settings.title'
        ]
    ];

echo $param[0] . '?' . 'fields=' . implode(',', $param['fields']);
// campaigns?fields=campaigns.id,campaigns.settings.title
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode('**&**') as you're currently doing on the path:

```
<pre>
<?php
$arr=array();
$str="0=campaigns&fields[0]=campaigns.id&fields[1]=campaigns.settings.title";
$arr=explode("&",$str);
print_r($arr);
?>
 </pre>
```

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the problem, a description of what your suggesting and why this solves the problem would improve the quality of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have strong concerns, that you really want to have such http string:

```
campaigns?fields=campaigns.id,campaigns.settings.title
```

**It means:** Go to the url `campaigns` with single http parameter `fields` which contain string `campaigns.id,campaigns.settings.title`.

I think you mostly should go with one of the possible variants as:

```
campaigns?fields[]=campaigns.id&fields[]=campaigns.settings.title
```

So you send fields array, that have 2 values
Or:

```
campaigns?campaigns[id]=xxxx&campaigns[settings][title]=yyyyy
```

To split your http params in a proper object

http_build_query builds only query part of the string which is `fields=campaigns.id,campaigns.settings.title` in your initial string. You can't get full string with http_build_query, but you can go with something like this:

```
'campaigns?' . http_build_query(fields: 'campaigns.id,campaigns.settings.title')
```

To get the exact string you wanted